# Groovy - @DelegatesTo(strategy=Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY, ...) unexpected behavior

Tags: groovy, delegates, annotations, closures

In this code, the assertion is failing:

```
class Foo { 
   def foo() { 'foo' } 
}

def foo() { 'foo2' }

def bar(@DelegatesTo(strategy=Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY, value=Foo) Closure c) {
   c.delegate = new Foo()
   c()
}

assert bar { foo() } == 'foo'
```

I expected the assertion to pass because the strategy is specified as `Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY`, and so it should only be trying to resolve `foo()` using the delegate which is `new Foo()`, otherwise throw an exception. I didn't think I'd have to specify the strategy explicitly again in the body of the function with `c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY`. That just seems verbose. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Please see if this example helps - http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/11/groovy-goodness-setting-closures.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link. My question revolved more around the semantics behind the annotation parameter `strategy` for `@DelegatesTo`. IOW, why is it still necessary to specify `resolveStrategy` when the annotation parameter specifies a resolve strategy already?

Comment: `DelegatesTo` is an annotation to help the compiler when it is running in static-type compilation mode.  I don't believe it has any effect on what you code does, or how you write it, it's more of a type-hint

Comment: Oh, so it's basically documentation?